# How to optimize a sum over list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I have to make a large computation (for statistics), but the following function is making haskell say nothing if n is close to 100, but I have to make n = 500. When I remove one of the factors (for example `(p**fromIntegral l))` things get better. Any idea how to make the sum more efficient? Also, the 'choose' function is from a library that is optimized (hackage said). Thanks a lot

```
probaMetodo :: Integral b => b -> b -> Double -> b -> Double
probaMetodo i j p n = sum [(p ** fromIntegral l) * (fromIntegral(n `choose` l)) * ((1-p) ** fromIntegral (n-l)) | l <- [i,i+1..j]]
```

Comment: Why is that returning a `Double`? All the operations are integral

Comment: Where do you define `choose`? The only version I can find on Hoogle is from QuickCheck and that type does not match so I'm assuming it's your own implementation or an import? That seems to me the most likely place where the definition is inefficient.

Comment: I assume it is something equivalent to ``choose n l = product [n-l+1 .. n] `div` product [1..l]`` in which case I have no trouble running e.g. `probaMetodo 200 300 0.6 500` in GHCi, it takes almost no time.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `p` is almost certainly a probability, so not integral.

Comment: Hayoo points out [`Numeric.SpecFunctions.choose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/math-functions-0.1.5.2/docs/Numeric-SpecFunctions.html#v:choose), which indeed computes a binomial coefficient (and happens to return a `Double`).

Comment: @duplode But then the code above wouldn't compile at all, due to the `fromIntegral`.

Comment: it is from this module:  Math.Combinatorics.Exact.Binomial

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oops, I had read it too quickly. @melody123 When trying it here, `probaMetodo 200 300 0.6 500` finishes near-instantly as Ørjan described even if using [the same `choose` as you](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exact-combinatorics-0.2.0.8/docs/Math-Combinatorics-Exact-Binomial.html). I guess we will need to know a little more about your scenario. Just to be 100% sure: have you tested `probaMetodo` separately from the rest of your code? If not, chances are sthat something else is blame for the slowness.

Comment: @duplode: Sorry I was afraid this would happen. I went through this with melody123 and the problem is indeed not in this function. Because I thought my answer was no longer useful, I deleted it (with the comments). I suggested melody123 would write a different question and close this one or edit this one, he wrote a [different one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611477/function-cannot-handle-big-values-of-n-close-to-400) but this one is not deleted yet (@melody123: I think this would be a good time for that).

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden Having a new question is not ideal, but I don't think deleting is necessary (specially given that deleting too many of your own questions early on can pave the way to a question ban). I suggest voting to close (none of the close reasons are a great fit, so I guess I'll just go with "unclear what you are asking") and linking the new question to this one to provide context.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden I read your comment too quickly and missed some of it (second time I do that in this question -- I probably need some coffee!), so I'd better correct the "not ideal" I wrote above. Generally speaking, radically changing your question after someone has answered is *not* okay, as it causes confusion and wastes the time of the answerer. In such cases, asking a new question (without deleting the old one) tends to be better. This question is kind of an edge case, though, as the original issue wasn't a problem at all and you, the answerer, deleted the answer of your own accord.