# function cannot handle big values of n (close to 400)

Tags: haskell

This is from a project for statistics. I defined the functions below, but the second is slow when n grows close to 400. The first method is fine (some people here have helped me [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608913/how-to-optimize-a-sum-over-list-comprehension))

```
import Math.Combinatorics.Exact.Binomial -- from `exact-combinatorics` package

probaMet :: [Integer] -> Float-> Integer -> Float
probaMet [i,j] p n = sum [(p**fromIntegral l)*(fromIntegral(n `choose` l))*((1-p)**fromIntegral (n-l)) | l <- [i,i+1..j]]


indices :: [Int] -> Float-> Int -> [Int]
indices [] _ _      = [1,2]
indices [i,j] p n
  | probaMet [toInteger i,toInteger j] p (toInteger n) >= beta  = [i,j]
  | otherwise                       = indices [(i-1),(j+1)] p n
```

I am supposed to make a computation with n=500, so any help would be great. This is what happens

```
 Main> indexEstadisticos [24,25] 0.25 100
[24,25]
*Main> indexEstadisticos [24,25] 0.25 250
[19,30]
*Main> indexEstadisticos [24,25] 0.25 400
```

Comment: Plese edit your question to add the definition of `beta`, so that we can run your code exactly as posted.

Comment: `beta = 0.01` seems to fit the test cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a rethink, completely changing my answer:

Your problem is that you are using `Float`, which only has single floating point precision, and already `0.25 ** 100 :: Float` is equal to `0`, which means no term with that high exponent will give *any* contribution to the sum. `0.75 == 1 - 0.25` lasts a little longer, but `0.75 ** 400 :: Float` is also `0`.

As a result, your sum becomes far too low, in some cases so low that no interval is found that exceeds your `beta`, causing an infinite recursion.

If you use the double precision `Double` instead, all your test cases will run, with the second one giving a different answer.  Mind you, if you go just a little further above `500`, even `Double` starts giving zeros.

Addendum: I thought again and my previous reasoning was still a bit off. The problem also involves the binomial coefficients becoming too *large*. When your original second case answered `[19,30]`, `probaMet` actually returned an `Infinity` value, and some others tests combine both too large and too small to give the dreaded `NaN`. The reason is still the use of `Float`, though.